# How to store tableview cell selected index data into Userdefault and use it into previous page tableview cell using Swift?

Tags: swift

My scenario, I am having two viewcontroller VC1 and VC2. Inside VC1 I am having one tableview with two cell for From and To translation language UI. 
Here From cell or To cell click to showing common VC2 language list in a tableview. Based on language selection I need to store the selection data to VC1 and need to assign VC1 tableview cell label (immediate updating).

Below code I am using, need to simplified also how to use stored values in VC1 within tableview cell.

Here, My Code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        if language_segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 { //from

       selectedFromLanguage = filteredLanguages[indexPath.row]
            fromLanguageID = selectedFromLanguage?.icon
            fromLanguageName = selectedFromLanguage?.languageName
            fromLanguageCode = selectedFromLanguage?.languageCode

        } else { //to

            selectedToLanguage = filteredLanguages[indexPath.row]

            toLanguageName = selectedToLanguage?.icon 
            toLanguageName = selectedToLanguage?.languageName 
            toLanguageCode = selectedToLanguage?.languageCode                    
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
   }

@IBAction func close_Click(_ sender: Any) {

        // From Language Responses
        UserDefaults.standard.set(fromLanguageID ?? "",, forKey: "icon")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(fromLanguageName ?? "", forKey: "fromLanguageName")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a delegate model to inform the first VC that the language has changed.

Here's an example. First define a delegate interface, e.g.:

```
protocol LanguageSelectionDelegate
{
  fun languageSelector(didSetFromLanguage: Int)
  fun languageSelector(didSetToLanguage: Int)
}
```

You can either define a single method that passes both (when OK is clicked on the second VC) or use two methods as here, that are called as soon as the user clicks an option (which you use could depend on whether there is a 'Cancel' option which closes the second VC without applying changes).

Make your first VC conform to this protocol, and add an implementation. Within that implementation you may only need to reload the table view data - without the code I don't know. E.g. (only showing the 'from' language change, but 'to' is identical almost):

```
class FirstVC: UITableViewController, LanguageSelectionDelegate
{
  private var fromLanguageId = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "fromLanguage")
  fun languageSelector(didSetFromLanguage languageId: Int)
  {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(languageId, forKey: "fromLanguage")
    fromLanguageId = languageId
    tableView.reloadData()
  }
}
```

This assumes that your `cellForRowAt` implementation will populate the cell according to the languageId. You need to store a delegate reference in the second VC, e.g.:

```
public val delegate: LanguageSelectionDelegate!
```

And make sure you initialise it in your first VC prepareFor(segue) function, e.g.:

```
let vc2 = segue.destination as! SecondVC
vc2.delegate = self
```

Your `didSelectRowAt` for the second VC would then become:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{
  tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
  if language_segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 
  { //from
    selectedFromLanguage = filteredLanguages[indexPath.row]
    delegate.languageSelector(didSetFromLanguage: selectedFromLanguage.id)
  } 
  else 
  { //to
    selectedToLanguage = filteredLanguages[indexPath.row]
    delegate.languageSelector(didSetToLanguage: selectedToLanguage.id)              
  }
}
```

There's no need to call `reloadData()` from this function. And note that you only really need to deal in a unique ID for the language (I've assumed an int here), rather than saving all details about it.